# Using a Yubikey setup on Windows on Arch Linux (Manjaro)

Tags: arch-linux, chrome, manjaro, yubikey

I have a YubiKey that was set up on Windows, and I'm trying to use that on Manjaro (on Chrome). I researched a lot on the Internet, but I don't seem to be able to solve the issue.

When using `ykman list`, I get the following:

```
YubiKey 5 NFC [OTP+FIDO+CCID] Serial: ...
```

I tried to follow [these instructions](https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000006449-using-your-u2f-yubikey-with-linux) on `yubico` Website.

Also, I found [ArchWiki article on YubiKey](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/YubiKey): I have `libu2f-host` installed on my machine, and I have added [`70-u2f.rules`](https://github.com/Yubico/libu2f-host/blob/master/70-old-u2f.rules) to `/etc/udev/rules.d/` directory (although the instructions say that when you install `libu2f-host`, the rules should be added automatically).

And, if I use the `ykman-gui`, I see these interfaces:
[image]

However, when I open Chrome and try to log in to a Website that's supposed to use the YubiKey, I get the following error:

[image]

which is saying:

```
No valid client certificate found in the request. No valid certificates found in the user's certificate store.
```

It may be worth noting that I get the same error message if I don't connect my YubiKey at all!

So, is there a way to make this work? Is there a step missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the website is expecting a client certificate, so it might be specifically supporting the PIV (Smart Card) mode of the YubiKey only, not the FIDO U2F mode.

To support that, you need the `ccid` and `opensc` packages installed, and the `nss` package for the `modutil` tool, and then Chrome browser needs to be configured to use the `/usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so`. To do so, first close all instances of the browser, and use a command like this:

```
modutil -dbdir sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb/ -add "Smart card/YubiKey PKCS#11" -libfile /usr/lib/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

Essentially, YubiKey PIV mode emulates a combination of a CCID-compatible smart card reader plus a PKCS#11 compatible smart card.

(Sources: [this part of the ArchWiki YubiKey page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/YubiKey#CCID_Smartcard) and the [instructions for CAC smart card authentication](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Common_Access_Card).)

CCID is the hardware standard for interfacing with things that look like USB-connected smart card readers, and PKCS#11 is the software standard for communicating with PIV smart cards. To bridge the gap between the two, the `ccid` driver for the `pcscd` service provides a PC/SC software interface for low-level communication with *any* smart card-like devices for *any* purpose, and `opensc` provides a library that uses the low-level PC/SC interface and provides a higher-level PKCS#11 compliant software interface for specifically PIV purposes. (Yes, it's a complicated, multi-layered system.)

[Chrome, like Chromium, uses NSS Shared DB at `$HOME/.pki/nssdb` for certificate management.](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_cert_management.md) The command adds a reference to OpenSC PKCS#11 library, which is used to access compliant smart card readers and similar devices: essentially it tells any device using the shared NSS DB (including Chrome) "you can use smart-card-like devices as a potential source of client-side certificates for authentication, and here is how you can communicate with the smart card reader subsystem of this computer."

This command does not require YubiKey to be connected at the time you run it, but it is essential that the Chrome browser is **not** running when you run the command: if the browser is running, it will have already read the NSS DB and will overwrite it with old values when it exits, effectively undoing the command.

For some reason, Chrome does not include a GUI for configuring this setting, and so the `modutil` tool from the `nss` package is required to configure it.

If you need to troubleshoot this set-up, first plug in the YubiKey and use `opensc-tool --list-readers` to verify that the OpenSC layer sees the YubiKey. The response should be similar to this:

```
$ opensc-tool --list-readers
# Detected readers (pcsc)
Nr.  Card  Features  Name
0    Yes             Yubico YubiKey OTP+FIDO+CCID 00 00
```

If this does not work, verify that the `pcscd` daemon process is running.

Then use `opensc-tool --reader N --name -v` where N is the "card reader number" of the YubiKey from the left-most column of the output of the previous command (should be 0 if you have no other smart card reader-like devices) to verify that OpenSC recognizes that PIV content exists on the YubiKey. The answer to the latter command should include this line:

```
Card name: Personal Identity Verification Card
```

The second part of troubleshooting would be to start the Chrome browser and go to Settings -> Advanced -> Privacy and security -> Manage certificates. At this point, the system should pop up a window prompting for the YubiKey PIN: this is a side effect of needing to access the YubiKey in order to display its information. This verifies that Chrome can now use the PKCS#11 library to access the YubiKey PIV functionality through OpenSC.

After entering the PIN, the "Your certificates" page of the "Manage certificates" display should indicate that there is at least one hardware-backed client certificate available. You can choose to view the certificate at this point: the information should match whatever is supposed to be on your YubiKey, i.e. if you have questions about the contents, you should ask the person or organization that issued the YubiKey to you.

If the certificate stored on the YubiKey is visible to Chrome, you should now be ready to access the YubiKey PIV-authenticated site. Once the browser has prompted for the YubiKey PIN, it will be able to access the YubiKey until you exit the browser or unplug the YubiKey, so it should not prompt for the PIN more than once per browser session.

If you have the browser already running when you plug in the YubiKey, it may take a few seconds to recognize that the YubiKey is plugged in. So after plugging in the key, you should wait a few seconds before clicking to a link leading to the authenticated site.

Comment: Thank you @telcoM for your answer, I will try to do what you said. Just a couple of questions: can you elaborate a bit of what this command is doing? How is it affecting Chrome? I don't see any mention of Chrome in the command (sorry if those are very stupid questions). Also, to run this command, do I need to have the YubiKey connected, or I can run it regardless, and it will work when I connect the YubiKey? Thank you

Comment: @Farzad I've expanded my answer to elaborate and to provide some background of what is going on, plus troubleshooting instructions for checking that it all works as it should.

Comment: OMG @telcoM, I can't put in words how amazing your explanation was (probably the best answer I've got on SO and family!). I wish there was something more I could do other than accepting this as the answer because you taught me a whole bunch of things here, thank you.
Just one quick question: how can someone find out which software uses which method for smart cards/etc. For example, the page for Chromium, how could I have found out about that?

Comment: Well, your error message indicated that the site expects a client certificate. The page for Chromium was the third hit for a Google search for "chrome client certificates Linux". Or you could have started trying to figure out what each of the various interfaces of the YubiKey actually mean, read the YubiKey documentation and found out that PIV means (emulating) a smart card with a certificate in it, then proceeded to research "how to use smart-card-like things with Linux and Chrome then?" Eventually you would have found essentially the same information.

Comment: Still, your explanation about was CCID is and how everything works, was really spot-on :)